# Is there any way to copy a file across two machines without making a local copy?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I am wondering if this possible to copy a file from one machine to another without making a local copy using .NET `File.Copy(...)` in a program running on third machine?

Comment: I wonder too. Maybe you could try it, and let us know?

Comment: You could use something like PSExec calls, but it would obviously have some issues as far as status updates for large files on the third machine

Answer (score 0):

Load your file into memory, and then save it to another machine.

```
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
using (var  sw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(newFilePath))
    sw.Write(buffer);
```

Comment: Might be problematic on large files, say a terrabyte or two. At least copy streaming.

Comment: You don't need the BinaryWriter. And take look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx

Comment: Well, the point is not to transfer bytes of file to be copied to the third machine where the program is running...

Comment: @QuéPadre In this case you must spawn task on one of these two machines.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Well it was for the most simple case.